# Display a form and post it to dabase

Tags: joomla-3.x, database, form

I want to insert a form in a default.php file and post it to the database.

How should it be done? By adding an XML form or creating a regular HTML form and posting it to the database through a function in a controller file? What's the best way to get it done?

Comment: It's generally recommended to use MVC with Joomla. You might find it useful to read https://docs.joomla.org/Model-View-Controller and https://docs.joomla.org/Basic_form_guide. The latter has a sample component which you can adapt to suit your needs if you like.

Comment: I mean should i use those XML's forms or just a regular form in the default.php file in the view folder? Because i'm already using MVC.

Comment: I mean could i create an xml file with a form there and render it to my default.php page?

Comment: I'd certainly recommend using Joomla's XML forms, as it's easy to build in validation, error handling, consistency of presentation etc. An advantage of building the form in the model is that it's straightforward to build in data validation and re-presenting the form data when errors occur. In the longer term I think you're going to find it better to align with the Joomla pattern, as in https://docs.joomla.org/Basic_form_guide#Sample_Form_2.